# How to deploy a scrapy project on ubuntu 16?

Tags: python, deployment, scrapy

I need to deploy a scrapy project on ubuntu 16 server. I need to know the proper steps to do it / documentation to follow, and I need to ensure it's working fine on its own if set to run periodically.

Comment: How a look at scrapydweb https://github.com/my8100/scrapydweb